# How to compute F1 score for Roberta model when outputs are one-hot encoded?

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I want to compute F1 score of my model on test data. I have 12 classes so actual output might look like this:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

and the predicted output might look like this:

```
[0.0557, 0.0952, 0.0811, 0.1133, 0.0613, 0.0594, 0.1092, 0.0866, 0.0880, 0.0882, 0.0559, 0.1061]
```

the probabilities that sum up to 1.

How do I compute F1 score with this?

Answer (score 0):

you just need to use `torch.argmax(input, dim, keepdim=False)`:

```
predictions = torch.argmax(model_outputs, dim=1)
```

and then if you want the one-ho version you can just use `torch.nn.functional.one_hot`

```
one_hot_predictions = torch.nn.functional.one_hot(predictions)
```

from there, you can compute the F1 score as you wish

Comment: I did that but when calculating F1 it says ValueError: When your inputs are multi-dimensional multi-class, you have to set the `mdmc_reduce` parameter. Do you know why is that happening?

Comment: @Josalo9 it's literally written everything in the error message... where you calculate the F1 for multidimensional class (one hot) you have to set `mdmc_reduce=True`